# Proving the Schwartz inequality, need some help

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

The question and my attempt can be found here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSkbv.jpg

I don't quite understand what i'm suppose to do. It says to prove the inequality with whatever so I tried to substitute and then factor and I thought it would just work out, but it didn't.

Thanks

Comment: What you have written in the picture says you're supposed to prove the *equality*

Comment: So that means, that I use = signs instead of <= signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work looks good. I think you are making things a bit too hard for yourself. I'll compute one side for you; then, hopefully, you can verify that the two sides are indeed equal. If $x_{1} = \lambda y_{1}$ and $x_{2} = \lambda y_{2}$, then we have:

$$ \sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}} =\sqrt{(\lambda y_{1})^{2}+(\lambda y_{2})^{2}}\sqrt{y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}}$$ 
Then, factoring out a $\lambda^{2}$, we find:

$$ \sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}} =\lambda\sqrt{y_{1}^{2}+ y_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}} = \lambda ((y_{1}^{2}+ y_{2}^{2})^{1/2})^{2}$$

But we can see that this is just

$$\lambda(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})$$

Comment: when factoring out the lambda, how come its ok to factor even though there is a sqrt(y_1^2+ y_2^2)?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I am using the general result that for positive $a, b$, we have $\sqrt{a^{2}b} = \sqrt{a^{2}}\sqrt{b} = a\sqrt{b}$.